# Is it possible to structure a generic method so T is optional?

Tags: c#, generics

Hard question to phrase, but if I have:

```
public class BunnyManager
{
    public Bunny<T> GetBunny<T>(string someJson)
    {
       return new Bunny<T>(someJson);
    }
}

public class Bunny<T>
{
   T parsedJson { get; set; }

    public Bunny<T>(string someJson)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(someJson))
            parsedJson = ConvertJsonStringToObject<T>(someJson);
    }
}
```

in some cases I want to get a Bunny object without any json, because the json string is null, so I don't care what T is.

In this case, can I create an overload or something to ignore `T` completely, or can I call `GetBunny<null>` or `GetBunny<object>`?

I'm wondering what the correct way to solve this might be.

Comment: `GetBunny<object>` is valid. Everything else not :-) Note that you can't even do `GetBunny<void>` (tried many times :-) )

Comment: Have you considered creating an IBunny interface and having your Bunny<T> derive from that? Then you can simply return an IBunny, which can either be of type Bunny (no generic because no parsed result) or Bunny<T> (where T is the parsedResult)

Comment: Awesome name for a class +1

Comment: You could try GetBunny<Void>. Void is an object which represents the void return type.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can have a non generic bunny class that the generic one inherits from.

```
public class BunnyManager
{
    public Bunny<T> GetBunny<T>(string someJson)
    {
       return new Bunny<T>(someJson);
    }

    public Bunny GetBunny()
    {
       return new Bunny();
    }
}

public class Bunny
{

}

public class Bunny<T> : Bunny
{
   T parsedJson { get; set; }

    public Bunny(string someJson)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(someJson))
            parsedJson = ConvertJsonStringToObject<T>(someJson);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is another big advantage on what you did: in `Bunny` you can put `object parsedJson { get; set; }` and in `Bunny<T>`: `new T parsedJson { get { return (T)base.parsedJson; } } set { base.parsedJson = value; } }`. Now `Bunny` can be used even without knowing the type of the parsed object

Comment: @xanatos I probably wouldn't design it like that if  `parsedJson` is not relevant in the non generic bunny class.

Comment: @xanatos: What is the need to have a parsedJson object in the base class that is always null? In addition I don't like the necessary casting that you introduced in the getter of parsedJson for the derived class and the use of the new keyword that hides the base property.

Comment: @LucaCremonesi The same reason that there is to have some `Bunny<>` objects that share a common class. Why is Magnus putting `Bunny` as a base class? Everything as written would work if `Bunny<T> : object`. In the end `Bunny<Foo>` and `Bunny<Bar>` are distinct (you can't cast one to the other... Unless you have their real type you can't do anything with them...). Why should they both be related to `Bunny`? Note that in the end, the one I suggested is the pattern used by classes that implement `IEnumerable<T>` + `IEnumerable` interfaces (`Current` is both `object` and `T`)

Comment: So simple, so elegant, extending the generic class into a non-generic class simply never occurred to me! Thanks for the answer, it is much appreciated :)

Comment: @xanatos: "Why should they both be related to Bunny?" Because they may share some of their members such as properties and methods. However the base Bunny class does not have the parsedJson property since this is relevant only to the derived generic classes.

Answer (score 4):

You can always create a non-generic base class

```
public class Bunny 
{
}

public class Bunny<T> : Bunny
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, if the class is generic, then all members are assumed generic, don't need a generic parameter - not even the constructor.

Second, if you don't care about `T`, then you can make an overload of `GetBunny` withuot `T`, since overloading classes and methods based on different generic parameters is allowed (see for example the [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classes.)

The easiest method I have found for generics without parameters is to make a nongeneric base class (`abstract class Bunny`) from which the generic inherits (thus `Bunny<T> : Bunny`) which makes it easier to keep, say a `List<Bunny>` of disparate types. This is particularly applicable in your case since the base class would be a less specific implementation and thus fit the usual pattern for inheritance.